# Can't delete files from Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, files

I try to delete a folder from `/var/www` but the I get the message, that operation is permitted:

```
$ sudo rm -Rf ./contao_old/
rm: cannot remove './contao_old/.git/objects/pack/pack-b3e96bac096853d13b620095481d9bf62f800011.idx': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove './contao_old/.git/objects/pack/pack-b3e96bac096853d13b620095481d9bf62f800011.pack': Operation not permitted

$ lsattr
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./pack-b3e96bac096853d13b620095481d9bf62f800011.idx
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./pack-b3e96bac096853d13b620095481d9bf62f800011.pack
```

I'm new to linux and don't understand that issue. I read something about mount, but in my opinion there is no mount.

Comment: `cat /proc/mounts´ please.

Comment: You should check this question: https://serverfault.com/q/324975/5643

Answer (score 0):

short answer:

`su -` to become root (I'm  supposing that you can do that)

then, go to your `/var/www` and execute

`# chown -R (your-normal-user):(your-normal-user) .contacto_old`

after that, change to your normal user with `Ctrl+D` and execute

`rm -rf .contacto_old`